# update nested value in object of objects with keys in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have a nested object:

```
myObject {
  "fshkj78gds": {
    "name": "Joe",
    "created_at": {
      "nanoseconds": 745000000,
      "seconds": 1645468219,
    },
    "updated_at": {
      "nanoseconds": 0,
      "seconds": 1645471800,
    },
  },
  "gsdg987": {
    "name": "Mike",
    "created_at": {
      "nanoseconds": 745000000,
      "seconds": 1645468219,
    },
    "updated_at": {
      "nanoseconds": 0,
      "seconds": 1645471800,
    },
  },
}
```

I would like to convert `created_at` and `updated_at` in each nested object to only return the `seconds` instead as a number like so:

```
myObject {
  "fshkj78gds": {
    "name": "Joe",
    "created_at": 1645468219,
    "updated_at": 1645471800,
  },
  "gsdg987": {
    "name": "Joe",
    "created_at": 1645468219,
    "updated_at": 1645471800,
  },
}
```

I am thinking I will need a mix of `map` and `Object.assign` as well as spread operator?

So far I got to:

```
Object.assign({}, myObject, Object.values(myObject).map((nestedObject) =>
  Object.assign({}, nestedObject, {...nestedObject, created_at: nestedObject.created_at.seconds})
))
```

But this generates an array of objects and doesn't keep the original structure. What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Can you modify the object in place, or do you need to return a new object?

Comment: modifying the original is fine

Comment: To do it in place (modifying the original array and its original objects), use a for loop, adding a field

Comment: These are all great solutions, so it's hard to select which one is the right answer. I'm choosing @Barmar because it's the one I chose to use since I can modify the original object and in my use case ended up being the least verbose. Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `forEach()` to iterate over the values and then just reassign the properties.

```
Object.values(myObject).forEach(item => {
    item.created_at = item.created_at.seconds;
    item.updated_at = item.updated_at.seconds;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Object#fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), [`Object#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const myObject = {
  "fshkj78gds": {
    "name": "Joe",
    "created_at": { "nanoseconds": 745000000, "seconds": 1645468219 },
    "updated_at": { "nanoseconds": 0, "seconds": 1645471800 }
  },
  "gsdg987": {
    "name": "Mike",
    "created_at": { "nanoseconds": 745000000, "seconds": 1645468219 },
    "updated_at": { "nanoseconds": 0, "seconds": 1645471800 }
  }
};

const res = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(myObject).map(([ key, value ]) => ([
    key,
    { ...value, 'created_at': value['created_at'].seconds, 'updated_at': value['updated_at'].seconds,  }
  ]))
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Very cool! This directly demonstrate all I asked about.

Answer (score 1):

```js
for (let key in obj) {
  obj[key].created_at = obj[key].created_at.seconds;
  obj[key].updated_at = obj[key].updated_at.seconds;
}
```